# Html5 based Loading Progress HUD

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hud

Just wondering if anyone can recommend a good loading HUD for a SPA based html page (written in asp.net mvc)?

Being a SPA based web app I want to be able to give user some type of UI based feedback while the client side page's data is being loaded into the page. I like the HUD in the new Windows Azure portal. Here is a snapshot of it (hard to see in snapshot, but the image in the center spins until page contents is loaded):
[image]

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a good selection over @ http://preloaders.net/ and http://ajaxload.info/ and

Answer (score 0):

Just show and hide a gif, like the ones at http://ajaxload.info/.